# Matching "---" in preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

```
#\b^([0-9]{7,8}(\s/[0-9]{4})?|Charges|[\-]{3}|UNIVERSAL\sCONNECTIVITY-DCS|FEDERAL\sREGULATORY\sFEE-DCS|PROPERTY\sTAX\sALLOTMENT-DCS|ADMINISTRATIVE\sEXPENSE\sFEE-DCS)\b#m
```

I'm trying to do a match on a set of very... variable data, and I cannot for the life of me determine how to match a three-dash string.

The regex in question is

```
[\-]{3}
```

In which I have tried a hundred combinations to get it to work, but it does NOT ever match 3 dashes for me.

Any ideas? =/

Comment: [Works for me](http://regexr.com?31q40)

Comment: It works for me too. Post your code, maybe it's related to PHP and not your regular expression.

Comment: this could be an alternative solution if (strrpos($mystring, "---") >= 0) { // bingo }

Comment: Ooh! I found the solution! the \b was causing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your RegEx for the three dashes works fine, there is something else in the rest of your bigger RegEx that is failing.

Proof:

```
$x = 'mi---hai';
echo preg_replace('/[\-]{3}/', '', $x); // echoes 'mihai'
```

Btw if you're trying to match a dash and there are no other characters before it in the character class then you don't need to escape it. `[-]{3}` will work just as fine, and `[-abc]` will match a, b, c or dash.

Comment: I'll accept your answer as you lead me to the correct answer-- The issue was the \b word boundary

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a character class for a single character, just

```
-{3}
```

or a simpler

```
---
```

will do fine.

Your pattern anyway should work, check if you have actual dashes and not other characters that **look** like dashes (like em dash).

Comment: `\b^([0-9]{6,8}(\s/[0-9]{4})?|Charges|---|UNIVERSAL\sCONNECTIVITY-DCS|FEDERAL\sREGULATORY\sFEE-DCS|PROPERTY\sTAX\sALLOTMENT-DCS|ADMINISTRATIVE\sEXPENSE\sFEE-DCS)\b`

is what I'm doing on:
`991305 /0992`

`991305 /1000`

`992034 /0771`

`992034 /1000`

`---`

`---`

`Charges`

`Charges`

with still no --- matches

Answer (score 0):

Ooh! I found the solution! the \b was causing it, since - isn't considered a word character. Oops!